# Как вызвать функцию после изменения ngModel?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Создал примерно такой инпут:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
```

Хотелось бы отследить изменение name через RxJS вместе с его замечательным Observer. В интернетах в основном предлагают использовать (ngChange). Не уж то не существует способа через Observer?

Comment: Есть разные способы, сказать какой лучше не возможно, все зависит от конкретной ситуации. Самый простой способ, действительно ngChange. Вот остальные: 1. BehaviorSubject - это один из видов Subject. Выполняет роль одновременно зрителя и зрелища (observer и observable). Для преобразования BehaviorSubject в Observer есть метод .asObservable() https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject 2. Нативный Get и Set с помощью Object.defineProperty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty 3. Обернуть модель в Proxy https://developer.mozill

Answer (score 1):

**1 Вариант (простой):**

Можно использовать событие `(ngModelChange)` и при его вызове производить необходимые действия.

Пример:

`<input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" />`

---

**2 вариант (RxJs):**

Использовать реактивные формы.

В коде создаем control:
`control: FormControl = new FormControl()`

Подписываемся на изменения:
`control.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => { код... })`

HTML шаблон:
`<input type="text" [formControl]="control" />`